# Why does a constant in `let` change with repeated calls?

Tags: list, quote, let-binding

Say we have such a `foo` function:

```
(defun foo (e)
  (let ((lst '(a b c)))
    (delq e lst)))
```

Then we use it in following way (sequentially evaluating one by one):

```
(foo 'c) ; => (a b)
(foo 'b) ; => (a)
(foo 'a) ; => nil
(foo 'b) ; => (a)
```

What happened here?

If I define another `bar` function:

```
(defun bar (e)
  (let ((lst (list 'a 'b 'c)))
    (delq e lst)))
```

Then use it in the same way:

```
(bar 'c) ; => (a b)
(bar 'b) ; => (a c)
(bar 'a) ; => (b c)
(bar 'b) ; => (a c)
```

The results here seem reasonable to me.

So question is, why the constant in the `let` form of the `foo` function behave in this way? Is it intended?

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16670989/850781

Comment: Another key quotation highlighted at the duplicate on S.O. is this (which is from `C-h f quote`): "Warning: `quote` does not construct its return value, but just returns the value that was pre-constructed by the Lisp reader". I think that newcomers to lisp are frequently oblivious to the whole concept of the lisp reader, and so taking some time to learn and understand the distinction between the "read" and "eval" stages is very beneficial to understanding the language in general, as well as specific issues like the one above.

Comment: @phils Do you mean that `'` is a reader macro, which is processed in "read" stage, while `(list 'a 'b 'c)` is evaluated in the "eval" stage?

Comment: Strictly speaking `'` isn't a reader macro in elisp (elisp doesn't have reader macros), but it certainly is processed during the read phase. That's not the important thing, though. My point was about understanding that the reader transforms all of the textual lisp code into lisp objects (once), and it is those objects that are subsequently eval'd (often repeatedly), rather than the text that you see.

Comment: And because objects are potentially subject to manipulation during evaluation (as in this question), what's being eval'd at any given time doesn't *need* to represent the code that was originally read. Of course in most circumstances it will do exactly that -- you don't often need to think in terms of objects. But knowing what's going on behind the scenes allows you to recognise and understand the situations in which this sort of thing is a factor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating symbol in function arguments affected by destructive operations?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45814/evaluating-symbol-in-function-arguments-affected-by-destructive-operations). That question was posted earlier than this one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is my answer to [the identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16670989/850781), appropriately edited:

### The Bad

`foo` is **self-modifying code**. This is **extremely dangerous**. While the *variable* `lst` disappears at the end of the `let` form, its *initial value* persists in the function object, and that is the value you are modifying. Remember that in Lisp [a function is a first class object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), which can be passed around (just like a number or a list), and, sometimes, *modified*. This is exactly what you are doing here: the initial value for `lst` is a part of the function object and you are modifying it.

Let us actually see what is happening:

```
(symbol-function 'foo)
==> (lambda (e) (let ((lst (quote (a b c)))) (delq e lst)))
(foo 'c)
==> (a b)
(symbol-function 'foo)
==> (lambda (e) (let ((lst (quote (a b)))) (delq e lst)))
(foo 'b)
==> (a)
(symbol-function 'foo)
==> (lambda (e) (let ((lst (quote (a)))) (delq e lst)))
(foo 'a)
==> nil
(symbol-function 'foo)
==> (lambda (e) (let ((lst (quote (a)))) (delq e lst)))
```

### The Good

In `bar`, `lst` is initialized to a *fresh* cons cell and thus is safe.
`bar` does *not* modify its code.

### The Bottom Line

In general, it is best to treat [quoted](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) data like `'(1)` as constants - do **not** modify them:

> `quote` returns the argument, without evaluating it.  `(quote x)` yields `x`.
>   **Warning**: `quote` does not construct its return value, but just returns
>   the value that was pre-constructed by the Lisp reader (see info node
>   [Printed Representation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Printed-Representation.html)). This means that `(a . b)` is not
>   identical to `(cons 'a 'b)`: the former does not cons.  Quoting should
>   be reserved for constants that will never be modified by side-effects,
>   unless you like self-modifying code. See the common pitfall in info
>   node [Rearrangement](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rearrangement.html#Rearrangement) for an example of unexpected results when
>   a quoted object is modified.

If you need to [modify a list](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Modifying-Lists.html), create it with `list` or `cons` or `copy-list` instead of `quote`, like you do in `bar`.

See [more](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-self-mod) [examples](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DestructiveOperations).

### ps - variable naming

Emacs Lisp is a [lisp-2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/850781) so these is no reason to name your variable `lst` instead of `list`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Also, I know ELisp is lisp-2 but still, I don't want to confuse myself. Something like `(list (list 'a 'b 'c))`(although it is in the `let` form) looks very confusing at the first sight.

Comment: yes that is very confusing!  But also really interesting, I had no idea of lisp-1 nad lisp-2s.