# Function arguments in quoted lists

Tags: quote

First example:

```
(defun first (a)
    '(a 1))
(first 2) => (a 1)
```

Second example:

```
(defun second (b)
    (+ b 1))
(second 1) => 2
```

How can I get `(2 1)` with `(first 2)`?

Comment: I strongly recommend reading this Q&A regarding the dangers of your initial approach: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
(defun first (a)
    (list a 1))
(first 2)
```

Result:

```
(2 1)
```