# Strange behavior pushing an element into the car of a list using a function

Tags: list

The following is a very simple function called `my-function` which begins by
setting the global variable `L` to be the list containing `nil`.  The next
step is to modify  `(car L)`, a.k.a. `nil`,  by pushing `foo` into it.  The value
of `(car L)` is then returned.

Since `(car L)` started out being `nil`, one expects it to become the
list `(foo)` and in fact it does, but only upon the first call.  The second time one calls `my-function`
a very unexpected behavior occurs in the sense that the
return value is `(foo foo)`.

```
(defun my-function ()
  (setq L '(nil))      ;; L is set to be  a list containing a single element, namely the empty list
  (push 'foo (car L))  ;; Push 'foo into (car L), which so far used to be nil. (car L) should therefore become the list (foo)
  (car L))             ;; Return (car L)

(my-function)          ;; Call my-function once

        ⇒ (foo)        ;; As expected

(my-function)          ;; Call my-function twice

        ⇒ (foo foo)    ;; WHAT ???????
```

Why on earth do we get **TWO** foo's?  `my-function` started out destroying whatever previous value `L` might have had, so the second call to my-function should return
the same thing as the first one!!!

Should one call `my-function` successively, we get longer and longer lists of `foo`'s.

This is a minimalist version of a problem I encountered elsewhere and
I'd really like to understand the reason for the behavior described
above.  Among other things I'd like to increase my understanding
of the rules of scope in elisp, which I suspect is what is
presently eluding me.

In particular I am not interested in workarounds, which I can easily
provide, such as replacing the line `(setq L '(nil))` by `(setq L (list nil))` (which actually also puzzles me a lot!).

EDIT:  Some users suggested the related question [Why does a constant in `let` change with repeated calls?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20535/why-does-a-constant-in-let-change-with-repeated-calls)
which is indeed pretty similar but the reliance there on the `let` construct perhaps obscures the real reason behind the phenomenon which, as pointed out by @phils
and @shynur, is an attempt to change the value of a constant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a constant in \`let\` change with repeated calls?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20535/why-does-a-constant-in-let-change-with-repeated-calls)

Comment: "*Quoting should be reserved for constants that will never be modified by side-effects, **unless you like self-modifying code**.*"

Comment: Please delete your question, which is a duplicate. Thx.

Comment: @shynur, thanks for weighing in!  Your point is the most important thing I learned asking this question.  As I found out, the same applies to constant vectors defined by `[...]`.  I wonder if there is any reason why lisp should not prohibit modification of such constants once and for all, the same way `(setq nil 1)` is prohibited.

Comment: @Ruy Possibly some function of effort involved and maintaining backward-compatibility. One large discussion on this took place in https://bugs.gnu.org/40671 (e.g. https://bugs.gnu.org/40671#135 (or 204, 234, 357, ...)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very important to understand that `'...` which means `(quote ...)`
is not a shorthand for making lists.  It's a form which causes lisp to
return, unevaluated, the object that was created by the lisp reader
(at read time).

If you quote a list and then *modify* the quoted list, it stays
modified.  If you want to create a list and then modify it, create it
(at eval time) with `(list ...)`.

Be sure to go over the distinct `read` and `eval` phases of lisp
execution.  Once you understand the distinction, `quote` will make
much more sense.

```
(defun foo () (list 'a 'b 'c)) => foo
(defun bar () '(a b c)) => bar

(foo) => (a b c)
(bar) => (a b c)

(delq 'b (foo)) => (a c)
(delq 'b (bar)) => (a c)

(foo) => (a b c)
(bar) => (a c)

(symbol-function 'foo) => (closure (t) nil (list 'a 'b 'c))
(symbol-function 'bar) => (closure (t) nil '(a c))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  However I should say that this is indeed very unnatural.  What you are saying amounts to the fact that changing the OUTPUT of a function `(delq 'b (bar))`
changes the function itself!  This is sure to raise eyebrows of any mathematician such as myself.

Comment: Correct, it's self-modifying code.  This is one example of the (in)famous "code is data" property of lisp.  Be careful with `quote`.  (See also the warning in `C-h f quote`.)

Comment: And to reiterate, I *highly* recommend that you research the way that lisp goes through distinct `read` and `eval` phases, so that you understand when those things happen and what they are doing.  (A lot of things fall into place once you understand this process.)

Comment: Should I assume that this weird behavior also applies to something like `(setq L [nil nil])`?  Here no `quote` is used but I understand that, whithin a constant vector, the elements are not evaluated either, right?

Comment: Yes, it does:
`(defun bar () [a b c]) => bar`
`(bar) => [a b c]`
`(aset (bar) 0 'x) => x`
`(symbol-function 'bar) => (closure (t) nil [x b c])`

Comment: Indeed; the function is simply returning an object which can be manipulated like any other.

Comment: And like `(list ...)` you can call `(vector ...)` to create a new vector.